# How to calculate average requests per seconds using awk or sed on Apache logs

Tags: sed, awk

I am trying to calculate the average requests per seconds for a specific period of time of my Apache logs.

I have been able to narrow the results down to the period I am interested in, as well as calculating the requests per second, but I am not able to calculate the average. Here is what I have so far:

`paste "/var/log/apache2/access.log" "/var/log/apache2/access.log.1" | awk ' $4>"[10/Feb/2013:16:48:00" && $4<"[10/Feb/2013:17:15:00" {gsub(/\[/,"");print $4} ' | sort | uniq -c`

Could anyone steer me in the right direction? I have mentioned sed or awk but I am happy to use something else.

Cheers

Comment: First of all: what is `paste` doing there?

Comment: I need to get the contents of all Apache log files and this seems to do the trick. What should I use instead? cat?

Comment: Definitely not `paste`: http://pastebin.com/r0UA4eUt. Either `cat` or none: `awk '{…}' /var/log/apache2/access.log /var/log/apache2/access.log.1`.

Comment: What kind of `awk` you have? `gawk` has some handy time functions the others not have.

Comment: thanks, I have removed the `paste` bit. I have `awk`, although I could install `gawk` if needed.

Comment: Two things: 1) `paste` is still present in your example. 2) All awk versions that I know of will threat `$4>"[10/Feb/2013:16:48:00"` as a string comparison and indeed your example does not work here.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel: [awstats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thor, I can assure you it works just fine to aggregate Requests per second (won't get me the average though). I left the original script so that the comments actually make sense in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've already worked out how to get your requests per second, you need to decide what your 'average' represents; i.e. average requests over a 60 second period, or 5 minutes, or 15, or what not.  Assuming it's over a 60 second, you could have your existing script append, every second, to a metrics log.  Then have another script, every second, in a loop perform the following:

```
# tail -n 60 | awk '{total = total + $1}END{print total}' / 60 | bc -l
```

This will spit out the average requests, per second, over a 60 second period.  To do it over 5 minutes:

```
# tail -n 300  | awk '{total = total + $1}END{print total}' / 300 | bc -l
```

If you need more clarification, feel free to comment.

Comment: Ideally I would have rathe have done it on the fly, but I guess I can output to an external file. Cheers

Comment: You could simply pipe your existing awk output to what I wrote to a variable updated every second,  then pipe it to my script. Am not home to write it now,  will update it later though.